# Is there any difference between a proper photon and a photon of thermal radiation?

Tags: radiation

Does a thermal photon radiate spherically whereas a photon radiates in a circle/beam?
How do you tell a thermal photon of, say 3 eV, from a photon of light?

Comment: @John Rennie, Now, if I got it right, visible light is just thermal radiation.Since it has roughly 4000°K, it is correct to say that if we concentrate enough photons we can melt down any metal?

Comment: Yes, bobie, that's correct. Google "solar furnace" for more information. Some can reach temperatures up to 3500°C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All photons are excitations of the photon quantum field. The *photon* is actually not a great description of propagating light - it tends to be far more useful when you're considering light exchanging energy with something else.

If you insist on a photon description then you'd have to treat the radiation as a superposition of photons. A beam of light would be a superposition of photons moving in roughly the same direction, while spherical radiation would be a superposition of photons moving in all directions.

Whatever the case, all photons are excitations of the same quantum field irrespective of their source, so the simple answer to your question is *no*.